# What is the alternate of UICollectionViewController in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Recently, I started playing with SwiftUI, I am finding alternate of each component of UIkit for SwiftUI.

```
UIViewController -> View
UITableViewController -> List
UINavigationController -> NavigationView
UITabBarController -> TabbedView
UIAlertController -> Alert
```

But I can't find the alternative of UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is none yet. You either encapsulate UICollectionViewController using a Representable protocol (check the [WWDC 2019 session 231 - Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/)), or you try to do your best with ScrollView, List and whatever is available in SwiftUI.